# SQL syntax error in Peewee example with primary key

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error, primary-key, peewee

I've got a simple Peewee database model following the [quickstart tutorial](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#quickstart) and am trying to add an instance to the database. It returns the error,

> 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'WHERE (`image`.`url` = \'foo\')\' at line 1'

I paired down the code as much as possible, but I can't locate my mistake. Here is my model in a minimal and reproducible (I hope, it reproduces on my machine) example. Edit the `MySQLDatabase` call to fit your setup. I started with an empty database named 'test'.

```
from peewee import *

database = MySQLDatabase('test', **{'password': '1234', 'user': 'root'})

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

class Image(BaseModel):
    url = CharField(primary_key=True)

database.connect()
database.create_tables([Image])

image_url = 'foo'
image_entry = Image(url=image_url)
image_entry.save()
```

The error is thrown by the last line of the example code. If I take a look in my database, I can see that the table 'image' was successfully created.

```
describe image;
```

returns

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+  
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |  
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+  
| url   | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |  
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The table is still empty as expected because the error comes during the save statement.

```
select * from image:
```

returns

```
Empty set(0.00 sec)
```

Comment: If someone could confirm that this is reproducible, it would also be helpful.

Comment: @philipxy This is a oversight in my example. I'll add this call and a bit more detail, but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you:

https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.2/peewee/fields.html#non-integer-primary-keys

```
from peewee import Model, PrimaryKeyField, VarCharColumn

class UUIDModel(Model):
    # explicitly declare a primary key field, and specify the class to use
    id = CharField(primary_key=True)
```

> Auto-increment IDs are, as their name says, automatically generated
>   for you when you insert a new row into the database. The way peewee
>   determines whether to do an INSERT versus an UPDATE comes down to
>   checking whether the primary key value is None. If None, it will do an
>   insert, otherwise it does an update on the existing value. Since, with
>   our uuid example, the database driver won’t generate a new ID, we need
>   to specify it manually. When we call save() for the first time, pass
>   in force_insert = True:

```
inst = UUIDModel(id=str(uuid.uuid4()))
inst.save() # <-- WRONG!!  this will try to do an update

inst.save(force_insert=True) # <-- CORRECT

# to update the instance after it has been saved once
inst.save()
```

Comment: What if I don't know whether my instance already exists in the database? Do I need to check in advance before doing the forced insert?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, I'd try doing the force insert and see it's behaviour

Comment: Doing a forced insert on an instance that is already in the database causes an error. I'll write a followup question about this.